# Firestore rules not allowing read given valid UID

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have written the following firestore rule to limit reads on the users collection by only allowing the request if the caller's UID matches the document ID. There is parity between the users collections' document ID and the UID in Firebase Authentication.

```
    function isAuthenticated() {
      return request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    // Users collection
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read: if isAuthenticated() 
        && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
```

I have a document in the collection with ID `Eli90wRvWkfKcOfn1C4DBDqxQTz1`. When hitting firestore with **the same authentication user**, I get the following error:

[image: Failed read with uid check]

If I remove the check for the `request.auth.uid == userId`, it results in this rule and a successful read:

```
    // Users collection
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read: if isAuthenticated();
    }
```

[image]

The query that is being called is:

```
export const getUser = (uid: string) => {
  return db.collection('users').where('id', '==', uid).limit(1).get();
};
```

I've seen many people use the UID check in their rules but why isn't it working in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your security rules match this code:

```
db.collection('users').doc(uid).get();
```

So here we access a single specific documents, with the document ID being the UID of the user.

---

If you instead want to query for the UID in a field in the document(s), you can secure that with these rules:

```
match /users/{doc} {
  allow read: if resource.data.id === request.auth.uid;
}
```

So now the rules match your original code, and only allow reading documents where the value of the `uid` field matches the `uid` of the current user.

Comment: What is `resource` in this context? I tried updating the rule like you suggested but it doesn't work with the query I wrote originally (with the `where` clause). Your insight into the query was helpful though! Changing to use `doc` fixes the problem.

Comment: `resource` is the document that is being consider by the security rules. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.resource. I see I had a typo in the field name though, so I fixed that now.